# Can i access Firebase Storage without Realtime Database&

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database do store and display data inside RecyclerView. Now i have a lot of images(54). I stored them in Firebase Storage. Here is my question, can i access them without created database nodes with they're access token in them to display them in RecyclerView?

Right now i'm using Firebase Realtime Database to get they're access token and to display them in RecyclerView like show in screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you make use of the appropriate [Cloud Storage methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) of the Firebase Client SDK for Android. This would allow you to retrieve download URLs for objects stored in Cloud Storage and then display them in your app without the need of a database.

However, the purpose of using either the Realtime or Cloud Firestore databases is to generate a single access token for that resource that can be shared and reused by multiple users at once. This greatly improves loading times for your application as you don't have to generate an access token for each client accessing the object.

While you could store these URLs inside of Cloud Storage itself in its own static object (e.g. `gs://your-app.appspot.com/shared/images.json`) using the appropriate permissions, it has the trade-off of not being easily editable and if you revoke the access token for it, you may break apps that rely on it.

As you are likely already making use of the Realtime Database in your app already (for user data, preferences, and other information), this benefit of storing these URLs in your database of choice outweighs the negatives.

Comment: I'm glad we have you around here ;)